# Mysql - Obtener resultado de una query cuando dos campos de la misma columna coinciden

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente query en mysql:

```
SELECT Expert.ID, Expert.Name, Expert.Surnames
FROM Expert

INNER JOIN ExpertHasCategory ON ExpertHasCategory.ExpertID = Expert.ID
INNER JOIN Category ON Category.ID = ExpertHasCategory.CategoryID

WHERE Category.ID in (1,2) 
                            
GROUP BY Expert.ID, Expert.Name, Expert.Surnames
```

Lo que quiero conseguir son los expertos que concidan solo que tengan el ID category 1 y 2. Ahora mismo esta actuando como un 'OR' y me devuelve los expertos que tienen el ID category 1 y 2, pero también me devuelve los expertos que solo tienen ID category 2.

Como podría solucionar este problema para que la query me devuelve solo los expertos que tienen el ID category 1 y 2.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

¡Saludos!

**EDITADO**

Os paso las tablas para que se pueda ver mejor:

```
 CREATE TABLE `Expert` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SignUpDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Surnames` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Workplace` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ServiceLaboratorySection` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AutonomousCommunityID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comments` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `AutonomousCommunityID` (`AutonomousCommunityID`),
  CONSTRAINT `expert_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`AutonomousCommunityID`) REFERENCES `AutonomousCommunity` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci


CREATE TABLE `ExpertHasCategory` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ExpertID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `CategoryID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ExpertID` (`ExpertID`),
  KEY `CategoryID` (`CategoryID`),
  CONSTRAINT `experthascategory_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ExpertID`) REFERENCES `Expert` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `experthascategory_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryID`) REFERENCES `Category` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci


CREATE TABLE `Category` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

¡Gracias de nuevo!

**EDITADO**

He hecho una prueba más fácil:

Los datos de la tabla ExpertHasCategory son estos:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Pues bien lanzo esta query y tampoco me devuelve resultados:

```
    select ExpertID from ExpertHasCategory WHERE CategoryID = 1 AND CategoryID = 2
```

Cuando realmente vemos que en la tabla tengo ExpertID que contienen la CategoryID 1 y 2. No lo entiendo...

Sigo investigango a ver.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que te devuelva solo las que tienen la categoria 1 y 2 entonces debes utilizar `AND` y no `OR`

`WHERE Category.ID in (1,2)`  Esto te devolverá los que tienen categoria 1 o 2 o ambas porque no importa si tienen las dos o no, mientras tenga una categoria de esas dos te las mostrará

`WHERE Category.ID = 1 AND Category.ID = 2` Aqui le estas diciendo que te muestre los registros que tienen la categoria 1 y dos solamente, es decir las que tienen ambas

Al menos eso es lo que entiendo de tu query, aunque seria mas facil ver como es la estructura de la tabla para responder mejor si es que no te funciona eso

Comment: Ya probé también esa manera y cuando lo hago el resultado es 0, es decir, no me devuelve resultado no se porque. Os voy a copiar la estructura de las tablas para ver si así podéis ver que sucede.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:
WHERE Category.ID **LIKE** 1 AND 2;

No tengo el MySQL a mano pero nada se pierde en probar

Comment: Nada, me pasa exactamente lo mismo que si uso directamente AND, no me devuelve nada

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Si no vas a tomar datos de la tabla category, no hace falta que la incluyas en el join, prueba con este query que hace 2 join contra la tabla ExpertHasCategory, en uno chequea que tenga la categoria 1 y en el segundo que tenga la categoria 2, si no tiene ambas no deberia salir el experto listado:

SELECT Expert.ID, Expert.Name, Expert.Surnames
FROM Expert

INNER JOIN ExpertHasCategory as EHC1 ON ExpertHasCategory.ExpertID = Expert.ID and EHC1.CategoryID=1

INNER JOIN ExpertHasCategory as EHC2 ON ExpertHasCategory.ExpertID = Expert.ID and EHC2.CategoryID=2

Comment: Haciendo esto que me comentas me dice el siguiente error: ""Not unique table/alias: ''ExpertHasCategory. Supongo que sera porque estoy haciendo dos joins a la misma tabla.

Comment: mi error, debi colocar el alias en lugar del nombre de la tabla en la condición del join: INNER JOIN ExpertHasCategory as EHC1 ON EHC1.ExpertID = Expert.ID and EHC1.CategoryID=1, de igual modo con el segundo join

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he podido **SOLUCIONAR**.

El problema es que **no se pueden usar AND para una misma columna**, ya que en mi caso, la columna CategoryID no puede ser 1 a la misma vez que 2, por lo que se tienen que hacer subqueries.

Al final para que me funcionará he tenido que hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT Expert.ID, Expert.Name, Expert.Surnames FROM Expert
INNER JOIN ExpertHasCategory ON ExpertHasCategory.ExpertID = Expert.ID
WHERE Expert.ID IN 
(
    SELECT ExpertID FROM ExpertHasCategory
    WHERE CategoryID IN (1,2)
    GROUP BY ExpertID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
GROUP BY  Expert.Id, Expert.Name, Expert.Surnames
```

El **número que igualamos al HAVING COUNT(*)**, **debe ser la longitud que tiene la clausula IN**, en mi caso como es CategoryID IN (1,2), la longitud para el HAVING COUNT(*) es 2.

Espero que esta solución sirva para alguien más en un futuro que se pueda encontrar con el mismo problema.

¡Muchas gracias!